# convert epoch time to time string upon receiving query result in angular type script

Tags: angular, typescript, time, epoch

here's the question I'm facing:
I have an angular script that queries a backend service and gets query result to show to the user.
One of the fields in query response is a time stamp and currently it's epoch time e.g. 1637726700094

This time stamp will be displayed in html page as a table column and ideally I can convert it to
date string. I managed to get this conversion done by using  | date. Now it's displayed as a human readable date string.

The problem is, I also have a filter to allow user to select certain rows to display.
Ideally, the user can type e.g. November 26, 2021 at 2:05:00 PM and filter will show certain records. However  it does not work as the filter still works on epoch time which is the data source to the table instead of the converted data.

Ideally, I can parse the data source and create a new data source which contains the data string and search would work. I can search for November 26, or 2:05, or 2:05:00 all based on text.

Instead of

```
return this.http.get<data[]>(this.url, { params});
```

Is there a way to process the data[] (converting epoch timestamp to time string) before return to the script to display?

---

here's the final solution I used in code:

```
).subscribe(rawData => {
        const newData: NewData[] = rawData.map( (datum) =>
        {
            return {
                timeStamp: this.datePipe.transform(datum.timeStamp, 'yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss'),
                name: datum.name,
                status: this.showStatusStr(datum.status)
            };
        });
        this.newDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(newData);
        this.newDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.hcDataSource.sort = this.sort;
        console.log(newData);
        console.log(this.newDataSource);
    });
```

Comment: Instead of 

    return this.http.get<data[]>(this.url, { params});

Is there a way to process the data[] (converting epoch timestamp to time string) before return to the script to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inject the date pipe into your code where you want to do this,
you can map over the array, and invoke the pipe's `transform` method for each value, e.g.

```
const data: Data[] = this.response.map( (datum) => 
   { 
     return {
      date: this.datePipe.transform(datum.epoch),
      name: datum.name,
      status: dataum.status
     };
   }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I can display time string by simply do a  timeStemp | data:'long' in the html. However the angular search/filter is based on data source instead of the display. What I would like to achieve is to allow user to search the data based on time string because epoch time value means nothing to end users. Let me give it a try with your suggestion.

Comment: You asked how to convert all of the data's timestamps to Dates in one shot - this is how.

Comment: If the result data  consists of three fields: epoch name status. how I can convert all epoch to time string in all returned records. thx.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include all three of your fields

Comment: Sorry for so many follow-up questions here.  I'm new to typescript. the current logic is that the service returns the query result as is (an array of rawData, epoc, name, status). The caller subscribes to the service script and hopefully transfer rawData to newData and then create a data source using new MatTableDataSource(newData) for display.  Is there a way to do the transform in side subscribe (rawData=> /* rawData ->new Data */  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(newData);?  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes. The sample code in the answer can be used exactly like that.

Comment: This seems to work for me:  subscribe(rawData => {
                const newData: HcData[] = rawData.map( (datum) =>
                {
                    return {
                        timeStamp: this.datePipe.transform(datum.timeStamp),
                        name: datum.name,
                        status: this.showStatusStr(datum.status)
                    };
                });
                this.newDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(newData);
                this.newDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                this.newDataSource.sort = this.sort;

Comment: I guess this will be last question from me: simple transform will only display date, How do I include more info as if I were doing epoch | date'medium' which gives  date and time up to seconds. Thx!

Comment: call the pipe's `transform` method, and pass the date and the format as parameters, e.g. `datePipe.transform(datum.epoch, 'medium')`